# Google Sheets User Defined Function Permission Error

Tags: google-sheets, permissions, user-defined-functions

Hi I am trying to run this simple UDF in Google sheets, but the cell where I put the function keeps giving me permission error. Is there a way I can reset the auth permissions again.

```js
/**
 * Multiplies the input value by 2.
 *
 * @param {number} input The value to multiply.
 * @return The input multiplied by 2.
 * @customfunction
 */
function DOUBLE(input) {
  return input * 2;
}
```

The Error I get is this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/soAkW.png)

Comment: You don't have `SpreadsheetApp.openById()` in your function though - are you sure this is the correct function? Can you please paste your list of scopes (viewable from `File > Project properties > Scopes`). Also, does this happen in just this sheet, or multiple sheets?

Comment: My scopes in project properties are :

2 OAuth Scopes required by the script:
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets

This only happens in this workbook. Same function in other new project/workbook works just fine.

Comment: Please update your question with this information.

Comment: I think I found the problem. I have this following openbyid in the same project which is a global variable: var ssDANAHM_PRODUCTS = SpreadsheetApp.openById("XXXXXXX");  When I comment this line of code. The UDF starts to work.

Comment: That is exactly the problem.